# Can't set a default value at drop down menu

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

```
$sql = "select custName from customer where active = 1 order by custName";
sult=mysql_query($sql);
echo"<select name='custNameColo'>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if($row['custName']==$_GET['defaultCust']) {
        echo "<option value=".$row['custName']."selected = 'selected'>".$row['custName']."</option>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<option value=".$row['custName'].">".$row['custName']."</option>";
    }
}
echo "</select>";
```

I want set a default value a drop down menu, but it doesn't work, please help me.

Comment: Your select field element has name `custNameColo` & you comparing with `$_GET['defaultCust']`.. Check again over there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You didn't added single quotes in the value of option tag before and after. I done it for you. The default value was not selected because value attribute was not properly closed.

```
$sql = "select custName from customer where active = 1 order by custName";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
echo "<select name='custNameColo'>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    if($row['custName']==$_GET['defaultCust']){
        echo "<option value='".$row['custName']."' selected = 'selected'>".$row['custName']."</option>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<option value='".$row['custName']."'>".$row['custName']."</option>";
    }
}
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: Its false. Quotes shouldn't be used in integer comparisons. Ever.

Comment: well, @igorpan i wanted to say that quotes in the option tag was missing! thats why he is not getting default value of select tag!

Comment: Oh, you had quotes in SQL though, so thats probably reason you got downvoted. Just a note, I didn't downvote it :)

Comment: Dear all, I got it. very very thanks a lot X 100000000000000000000

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$sql = "select custName from customer where active = 1 order by custName";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['custname'] ?>" <?php if($row['custname']==$_GET['defaultCust']) { echo "selected";}?>>
<?php echo $row['custname']; ?></option>
<?php
}
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?  echo "TRY this it will work";
$sql = "select custName from customer where active = 1 order by custName";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
?>
<select name="custNameColo">
<? 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){?>
<option value="<?=$row['custname'];?>" <? if($row['custname']==$_GET['defaultCust']){?> selected="selected" <? }?>><?=$row['custname'];?></option>
<? } ?>
</select>
```